# Query int for searching in cosmos db?

Tags: int, azure-cosmosdb, contains

We have stored following document

> Document 1-  {
>   "Sample1":1,
>   "Sample2":"SampleData"
>   }
>
> Document 2-  {
>   "Sample1":10,
>   "Sample2":"Sample"
>   }
>
> Document 3-  { "Sample1":3, "Sample2":"Sample" }

We have to query like if user searches for 1 then it should return both documents and we don't know which type of data is stored in cosmos db.
How should I query this

```
select * from c where contains(c.Sample1, 1)
```

is not returning any results and for string i have to use contains
Can anyone please help me how i have to query int using contains?

Thanks,
Shraddha Agrawal

Comment: Don't get your idea.You mean you stored 2 documents listed with the yellow area, and you want to query which document has property: `"Sample":1`?

Comment: Please show your sample documents stored in your cosmos db and what's the result you want to get.Thanks.

Comment: I want to query int values as a string 10 also contains 1 hence it should return both documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your requirements is really odd,i provide a workaround that using UDF feature in cosmos db.

Create User Defined Function:

[image]

```
function userDefinedFunction(val){
    return val.toString()
}
```

Then use sql:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
where CONTAINS(udf.convertToString(c.Sample1),"1")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @AgrawalShraddha You're welcome,you could accept it to end this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use **`Contains`** as its not an **`array`**, you could simply write a where clause,

```
SELECT p
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.Sample1 = 1
```

**EDIT:**

As Jay mentioned above, you can use User Defined function. One of the other method you could use is STARTSWITH

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
where STARTSWITH(udf.convertToString(c.Sample1),"1")
```

Comment: I want to query int values as a string 10 also contains 1 hence it should return both documents

Comment: then dont add the where query

Comment: How to query above results?